# Using NSLog for debugging

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, nslog

I have the following code snippet in my Xcode:

```
NSString *digit [[sender titlelabel] text];
NSLog([digit]);
```

I tried to build the application and am getting the following warning message for the line `NSLog([digit]);`

```
Warning: Format not a string literal and no format arguments
```

Can you advise me how I can resolve this warning message? What does the message actually mean?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try this piece of code:

```
NSString *digit = [[sender titlelabel] text];
NSLog(@"%@", digit);
```

The message means that you have incorrect syntax for using the `digit` variable. If you're not sending it any message - you don't need any brackets.

Comment: Hmmm, why can't you just pass in NSLog(digit) directly? I think that will result in an warning, but why?

Comment: If you will get used to passing NSString objects directly - you will develop a habit of doing so. And sometimes you may pass not the object, but primitive type like float or int which will blow up your app at the point of logging.

Comment: @mingyeow It's also a security risk to pass a non-literal format string. Many systems have been compromised this way, by calling printf on a format string that was passed in by an attacker.

Answer (score 30):

Use `NSLog()` like this:

```
NSLog(@"The code runs through here!");
```

Or like this - with placeholders:

```
float aFloat = 5.34245;
NSLog(@"This is my float: %f \n\nAnd here again: %.2f", aFloat, aFloat);
```

In `NSLog()` you can use it like `+ (id)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...`

```
float aFloat = 5.34245;
NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is my float: %f \n\nAnd here again: %.2f", aFloat, aFloat];
```

You can add other placeholders, too:

```
float aFloat = 5.34245;
int aInteger = 3;
NSString *aString = @"A string";
NSLog(@"This is my float: %f \n\nAnd here is my integer: %i \n\nAnd finally my string: %@", aFloat, aInteger, aString);
```

Answer (score 5):

Why do you have the brackets around `digit`?
It should be

`NSLog("%@", digit);`

You're also missing an `=` in the first line...

`NSString *digit = [[sender titlelabel] text];`

Answer (score 4):

The proper way of using NSLog, as the warning tries to explain, is the use of a formatter, instead of passing in a literal:

Instead of:

```
NSString *digit = [[sender titlelabel] text];
NSLog(digit);
```

Use:

```
NSString *digit = [[sender titlelabel] text];
NSLog(@"%@",digit);
```

It will still work doing that first way, but doing it this way will get rid of the warning.

Comment: Hmmm, from xcode, i notice that the NSLog is expecting a (NSString * format,...). What exactly does the *format mean?

Comment: @ming yeow - This is the autocomplete telling you that the first parameter of the function is an NSString, `format` being the name of the paramter they use as an example to tell you that it should be a formatted `NSString`.  The `...` is a comma separated list of values that will be passed into the formatted `NSString`.  For example, if I put `NSLog(@"You passed %i and %i", 4,5);` it would output in the console: `You passed 4 and 5`.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSLog(@"%@", digit);
```

what is shown in console?

Answer (score 3):

type: BOOL

DATA (YES/NO) OR(1/0)

```
BOOL dtBool = 0;
```

OR

```
BOOL dtBool = NO;
NSLog(dtBool ? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

OUTPUT: NO

type: Long

```
long aLong = 2015;
NSLog(@"Display Long: %ld”, aLong);
```

OUTPUT: Display Long: 2015

```
long long veryLong = 20152015;
NSLog(@"Display very Long: %lld", veryLong);
```

OUTPUT: Display very Long: 20152015

type: String

```
NSString *aString = @"A string";
NSLog(@"Display string: %@", aString);
```

OUTPUT: Display String: a String

type: Float

```
float aFloat = 5.34245;
NSLog(@"Display Float: %F", aFloat);
```

OUTPUT: isplay Float: 5.342450

type: Integer

```
int aInteger = 3;
NSLog(@"Display Integer: %i", aInteger);
```

OUTPUT: Display Integer: 3

```
NSLog(@"\nDisplay String: %@ \n\n Display Float: %f \n\n Display Integer: %i", aString, aFloat, aInteger);
```

OUTPUT:
String: a String

Display Float: 5.342450

Display Integer: 3

http://luterr.blogspot.sg/2015/04/example-code-nslog-console-commands-to.html

Comment: What kind of answer is this? Was it just straight copy-pasted from the blog post?

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Is this a ***bogus answer?*** Put something from the question into a search engine and blindly copy-paste the first result into the answer box? Why does it have 4 upvotes? How does it answer the question: *"Warning: Format not a string literal and no format arguments ...Can you advise me how I can resolve this warning message?"*

Comment: [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554204/ios-6-rotation-issue-no-rotation-from-presented-modal-view-controller/29664074#29664074) reveals `http://luterr.blogspot.sg` was Luter Rinding's own blog (now defunc).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog([digit]); // [] are the messages in Objective-C, just like methods or functions in other programming languages
```

Since you just need to print the value of 'digit'

Either you can call -

```
NSLog(digit); // A warning would occur - Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)
```

OR

```
NSLog(@"%@",digit]); // But if you use %@ to reference the object, the warning will go away.
```

Both the methods will work but the second one is the right way of logging to console.