# How do I log a url with NSlog

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

Currently we are trying to log a url using a breakpoint in XCODE. It's printing out the log message and the memory address.  We would like to log the actual URL and not the Memory address.

Question:  What is the correct way to log a url in xcode using breakpoints?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode - Using NSLog for debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486270/xcode-using-nslog-for-debugging)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you mean something like:

```
NSLog( @"url is %@", [yourURL absoluteString]);
```