# ios - NSArray unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an instance variable _sessions of type NSArray.
Throughout the TableViewController methods, I access it and it is fine. But when in prepareForSegue, I try to access it or its values, it throws this error..

Relavent code:

```
@interface SessionsTVC()
{

    NSArray *_sessions;
    JSONDataRetriever *jsonRetriever;
    NSString *requestURL;
}
@end
```

in @implementation:

```
_sessions = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:_tempArray];
```

Lines giving me trouble:

```
NSLog([_sessions objectAtIndex:1]);
```

or

```
NSLog(_sessions);
```

What is even weirder is that this works:

```
NSLog([@(_sessions.count) stringValue]);
```

EDIT:

NSLog([@(_sessions.count) stringValue]); gives me back 2 (which is exactly right)..

FULL ERROR MESSAGE

2014-08-13 23:14:46.548 ReadDatabase[15142:650918] -[Session length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb5fbf55090
2014-08-13 23:14:46.644 ReadDatabase[15142:650918] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Session length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb5fbf55090'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001074313e5 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001070e1967 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001074384fd -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001073907ec ___forwarding_** + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107390388 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010732a39b **CFStringAppendFormatCore + 235
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107411c00 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 256
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107420a4f _CFLogvEx2 + 127
    8   Foundation                          0x0000000106c7da22 NSLogv + 99
    9   Foundation                          0x0000000106c7d9a7 NSLog + 148
    10  ReadDatabase                        0x00000001054a36f6 -[SessionsTVC prepareForSegue:sender:] + 518
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000105f04716 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 151
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000105aa0d40 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1242
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000105aa0eb4 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 219
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001059dc97e _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 314
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001059dc7f8 _afterCACommitHandler + 516
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107366337 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107366290 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010735c0c3 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010735b9f6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010960c9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001059b9990 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    22  ReadDatabase                        0x00000001054a2bf3 main + 115
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109def145 start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Please include error in question (not only title).

Comment: Please copy/paste the *full error*, including the jargon after that text.

Comment: yes please add your error description as well

Comment: The error message tells you precisely what's wrong, if you bother to read it.  Or if you post it here then we can read it and tell you what's wrong.  Lacking that, though, there's no point in even asking the question.

Comment: I assure you I played around with the error for hours without any luck. I cannot possibly understand how the [_sessions count] message could work fine but anytime I try to access items stored in _sessions, I get the error. THE FULL ERROR has been added to the question. Thank you folks.

Answer (score 1):

NSLog requires a string as the first argument.

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", _sessions);

NSLog(@"%@", [_sessions objectAtIndex:1]);
```

make sure that _session.count is grater than one in the second case.

Comment: NSLog can also take any nsobject and print its +(nsstring*)description. since all objects are descendants of NSObject that shouldn't be the reason for crash.

Comment: Where did you read this? The function signature is "void NSLog(NSString *format, ...)".

Comment: yeah my bad, it should have a format specifier, i just did a quick check.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html search for printf which talks about this, it do needs format specifier

Comment: I'm afraid that is not the problem since before the log message, I was actually doing stuff with the object returned by the message and it still resulted in the error.

Comment: As I told, the ONLY problem is that you are passing a non string variable in the first argument. The error log clarifies that... It is trying to access the method length (from NSString) of your _session variable. Trust me... Use the form **NSLog(@"%@", object)**. To log the count property (which is an int), pass @"%d" as the format instead of @"%@". [basic explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486270/xcode-using-nslog-for-debugging)

Answer (score 0):

What result do you get with this line:

```
NSLog([@(_sessions.count) stringValue]);
```

?

Because I think it is equivalent to:

```
NSLog([[NSNumber numberWithInt:_sessions.count] stringValue]);
```

Probably the issue is _sessions is nil, therefore _sessions.count will return 0, and you will see 0 as a string in the Console.

BTW, this is the correct way to print objects with NSLog():

```
NSLog(@"%@", [_sessions objectAtIndex:1]);
```