# Delegate assignment causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

I am trying to create a delegate for an `NSTextField` in my view controller, but the program crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Why does this happen? I read that I am calling a non-existent object, but I don´t know what does not exist. I am using ARC.

This is how the delegate object is created in my view controller:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Delegate.h"

@interface ViewController : NSViewController <NSTextFieldDelegate>{
}
@end
```

--

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSTextField* textField1 = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(200, 200, 150, 20)];
    [self.view addSubview:textField1];

    Delegate* delegate1 = [[Delegate alloc]init];
    [textField1 setDelegate:delegate1];
}

@end
```

Why does my program crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `delegate1` is release, in `viewDidLoad`

`Delegate* delegate1 = [[Delegate alloc]init];`

You should create a var for handling it in `ViewController.h`. Then

`delegate1 = [[Delegate alloc]init];`

Comment: I created in the `Viewcontroller.h` an instance of my delegate: `Delegate* delegate;` and I deleted the `Delegate* delegate1 = [[Delegate alloc]init];` in the `Viewcontroller.m`. Its still doesn´t print "ABC" in the console ;(. But this time it doesn´t crash ;)

Comment: Don't delete it. Try my answer please. Replace with `delegate1 = [[Delegate alloc]init];`

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works now. But why do I have to write the `delegate1` one time in `interface` and in `implementation` of the `ViewController` ?

Comment: I recognized that it prints "ABC" into the console, but doesn´t create the textfield. Why does the delegate method not create a new textfield ?

Comment: Because if you don't have any pointer to handle `delegate1`. It will be released. For the textfield, check IBOutlet window1, and frame of window1 vs textfield

Comment: I don´t understand your help. Can you give me some code example ?

Comment: Check in InterfaceBuilder. And try to log `window1.frame`. Maybe textfield go out side the window. Or you did connect window1 with InterfaceBuilder

Comment: Its still doesn´t work. How should I log `window1.frame` ?

Comment: Use `NSLog` to print to cmd. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486270/using-nslog-for-debugging

Comment: Thank you ! I added `NSLog(@"%@",[NSValue valueWithRect:textField2.frame]);` into the `Delegate.m` file. This is what appears on the console: `2015-08-26 15:12:32.747 Delegate_Test[1942:93806] NSRect: {{30, 30}, {170, 20}}`.

Comment: How about windown1.frame?

Comment: Why did you create textfield with `NSMakeRect(300, 300, 170, 20)`, but the log is `{{30, 30}, {170, 20}}`?

Comment: Oh, I was playing around with the values. Now it logs `textField2:   NSRect: {{300, 300}, {170, 20}}`. When I write `NSLog(@"%@",[NSValue valueWithRect:window1.frame]);` into the `Delegate.m` my programm logs: `NSLog(@"%@",[NSValue valueWithRect:window1.frame]);`. Event when I write into the code:  `[window1 setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 800, 800)];` it logs `2015-08-26 18:10:56.355 Delegate_Test[2364:134180] NSRect: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}`

Comment: See, the problem is `window1.frame`. Check the connection of window1 (with IB). Did you connect it?

Comment: Yes, I connected it. I think I made something little wrong and it drives me crazy. It still doesn´t work.

Comment: Do you use auto-layout? Or you can search window1  to see what you did with it.

Comment: Yes, but even with turning auto-layout off it doesn´t work.

Comment: Do you see the window1 is displayed?

Comment: No, but I don´t know how to solve it. Perhaps I can upload my project and you can check it ?